Advice working on Euler 10, attempting to understand the Sieve of Eratosthenes
I've been working on this problem 10 for the last couple days and i've been trying to improve runtime and not have it take over half an hour to an hour to run. At first it was checking each value if prime and removing, then I discovered Sieve of Eratosthenes and have tried implementing it. I'm unsure if I'm even making an improvement here.
goal = 2000000
allBelow = [int(x) for x in range(0,goal)]

def sieveOut(lst:list,value:int):
    index = lst.index(value)
    while index < len(lst):
        v=lst[index]
        if v != value and v%value == 0:
            print("REMOVING: " + str(v))
            lst.remove(v)
        index+=value
    return lst

index = 0
allBelowLength = len(allBelow)
while index < allBelowLength:
    value = allBelow[index]
    if value <= 1:
        print("Removing " + str(value))
        allBelow.remove(value)
    else:
        print("Sieving out " + str(value))
        allBelow = sieveOut(allBelow,value)
        index += 1
    allBelowLength = len(allBelow)

print(str(allBelow) + " :: " + str(sum(allBelow)))


You don't .remove the non-primes, you just mark them. Every .remove has to (1) search the resp. list entry again and (2) modify the list structure (which costs a lot).

It looks like you are on a good track with the Sieve of Eratosthenes, but your implementation could be improved. The lst.remove(v) is probably the crucial point, as all elements have to be shifted.
Your implementation could be improved like this:
def sieve_of_eratosthenes(max_number):
    is_a_prime_number = [True for i in range(max_number+1)]  # at first, no values are sieved out
    p = 2  # p is the number being checked. starts at value 2 and counts up the squareroot of max_number
    while (p ** 2 <= max_number):
        if is_a_prime_number[p]:  # this gets false for numbers where we actually know that they are no prime numbers (e.g., 6: we do not need to check multiples of 6, because the have been sieved out by 2)
            for i in range(p ** 2, max_number+1, p):
                is_a_prime_number[i] = False
        p += 1
    prime_numbers = [p for p in range(2, max_number) if is_a_prime_number[p]]
    return prime_numbers

